# Workbook_Open MsgBox Pop-up with a list of cell changes from day before

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating this worksheet with a series of drawing packages (i work as an engineer). I would like my users to be able to see a list of the drawing packages which I've revised the day before upon them launching the excel app. 
I want a popup msgbox showing that list.
So i did some research, i know i need to set up a change detection macro (to detect the cell's I've changed) and a workbook_open with a message box with the list of cells which were modified the day before.

I have no clue how to insert a cell value with the msgbox line of code, or how to go about setting this whole thing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here how I might do it. I maintain a hidden sheet where I track all the changes that I do TODAY using `Worksheet_Change`. And when I open the workbook tomorrow then I simply retrieve the changes from the hidden sheet using `Workbook_Open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Siddharth - the easiest way to do this would probably be to use a buffer worksheet.

You could create the buffer every day and then compare your entered data to the buffer when you open the workbook. And then create an updated buffer.

This will work; although instead of using a message box it just highlights the cells on sheet1 and in column A that were changed on last open - I personally would prefer to just have the cells highlighted - but if you are heart-set on a message box that shouldn't be too much more difficult:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

ClearSheet1Formatting

CompareValuesBetweenTwoWorksheets

MsgBox "Hi, thanks for opening me Dora. The cells that are highlighted were changed on last open."

UpdateBufferSheet

End Sub


Sub CompareValuesBetweenTwoWorksheets()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim jj As Long
Dim CheckColumn As Integer
CheckColumn = 1
Set s1 = Sheet1
Set s2 = Sheet2
j = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, CheckColumn).End(xlUp).Row
For jj = 1 To j
    If s1.Cells(jj, CheckColumn).Value <> s2.Cells(jj, CheckColumn).Value Then
        s1.Cells(jj, CheckColumn).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub UpdateBufferSheet()

Application.CutCopyMode = True

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub ClearSheet1Formatting()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

I simplified this and made the sub names better.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the code. What does it do? I thank you for taking the time to help me. If it is not too much, could you maybe explain it to me?

Comment: Sure, Basically Macro1() copies the contents of sheet1 to sheet2. Macro2() clears any highlighting from sheet1. CompareValuesBetweenThreeWorksheets() compares the values on sheet1 to the values on sheet2 and highlights any differences in column A on sheet1. Auto_Open is the function that runs automatically when you open the workbook. So first Auto_Open() clears the previous highlighting on sheet one, then it compares to sheet two and highlights differences, then it's spits out that friendly message box, then it updates the buffer with macro2(). Try it out and it will be easier to understand.

Comment: See my edit: I simplified the code and made the names of the subs more descriptive.